# KQL - Include Time zone in the Kusto Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a task to convert Dashboards from Splunk to Kusto.I see the difference in data due to the Splunk has the data table in UTC time zone but I think Kusto is taking my local Time zone. 1) Is there a way to Query in Kusto to identify the current Time zone for Data . 2) Convert Kusto table or Query to use the UTC time zone to match with Splunk Data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quoting the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime):

> A `datetime` value in Kusto is always in the UTC time zone. Displaying `datetime` values in other time zones is the responsibility of the user application that displays the data, not a property of the data itself. Should time zone values be required to be kept as a part of the data, a separate columns should be used (providing offset information relative to UTC).